# Fatal Error - Unable to parse XML document with Java code

Tags: java, xml

I have an XML file which I want to parse(below). I used an example on mykong to learn - 
http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-xml-file-in-java-dom-parser/comment-page-2/#comment-125087
But I got an error "[Fatal Error] flight.xml:3:15: Open quote is expected for attribute "{1}" associated with an  element type  "id"."

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root xmlns:android="www.google.com">
<passenger id=001>
<name>Tom Cruise</name>
</passenger>
<passenger id=002>
<name>Tom Hanks</name>
</passenger>
</root>
```

I changed the print statements, but it does not work.

```
System.out.println("Passenger id : " + getTagValue("passenger id", eElement));
System.out.println("Name : " + getTagValue("name", eElement));
```

How do I edit the code in mykong to make it work for me ?

**Update -**  I made the changes as mentioned below. But, now I don't see the passenger id's and names in my output. How do I fix that ?

New XML File here -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root xmlns:android="www.google.com">

<passenger id="001">
<name>Tom Cruise</name>
</passenger>

<passenger id="002">
<name>Tom Hanks</name>
</passenger>

</root>
```

Comment: If an XML parser tells you that it can't parse your file, then it's almost certainly right: you can't use an XML parser to parse something that isn't XML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No xml parser will ever accept id=001. It should be either id="001" or id='001'. These are the miminum requirements for a so-called **well-formed** xml document otherwise it is not an xml document

```
•XML documents must have a root element
•XML elements must have a closing tag
•XML tags are case sensitive
•XML elements must be properly nested
•XML attribute values must be quoted
```

Besides, make this changes to the code

```
public static void main(String argv[]) throws Exception {
    File fXmlFile = new File("c://file.xml");
    DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document doc = dBuilder.parse(fXmlFile);
    doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
    System.out.println("Root element :" + doc.getDocumentElement().getNodeName());
    NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("passenger");
    System.out.println("-----------------------");
    for (int temp = 0; temp < nList.getLength(); temp++) {
        Node nNode = nList.item(temp);
        if (nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
            System.out.println("Passenger id : " + e.getAttribute("id"));
            System.out.println("Name : " + e.getElementsByTagName("name").item(0).getTextContent());
        }
    }
}
```

output

```
Root element :root
-----------------------
Passenger id : 001
Name : Tom Cruise
Passenger id : 002
Name : Tom Hanks
```

Comment: I made the changes as mentioned below. But, now I don't see the passenger id's and names in my output. How do I fix that ?

Comment: @Apple Grinder
xml tags attribute should be approached using the: elementNode.getAttribute(attribute_name)

Comment: @Apple Grinder fixed my answer, should help

Comment: @EvgeniyDorofeev - Sorry, it did not change the output. Should'nt the code be like this - 
        System.out.println("Passenger id : " + eElement.getAttribute("passenger id").trim());
        System.out.println("Name : " + eElement.getAttribute("name").trim());

Comment: @Apple Grinder full main() is in the answer it works ok on my PC see output

Comment: @EvgeniyDorofeev - Some doubts remain though. Why did we have to use trim() ? I tried the code without trim and the output was not neatly formatted. and why does e.getAttribute() give me passenger id even when you pass it "id" instead of "passenger id".

Comment: Right, we don't need trims, see latest update;  "passenger id" is wrong,  the element name is "passenger", the attribute name is "id"

Answer (score 1):

The id attribute should start and end with double quote.

```
<passenger id="001">
```

And also dont forget to close your passanger tag (dont see that in your example).

Answer (score 0):

you are closing the name tag twice even thought you only open it once. You should be wanting to write something like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root xmlns:android="www.google.com">
<passenger id=001>
<name>Tom Cruise</name>
<passenger id=002>
<name>Tom Hanks</name>
</root>
```

Comment: oops ! my bad. The extra closing tags were supposed to be passenger and not name. btw, your code will also cause errors.